# What should our logo and site design look like?

Tags: discussion, design

It's not being so long since we've entered public beta, but time could be needed for this matter.

Even if Stack Exchange team have designers, proposing your ideas have chances to help and influence them for our theme creation.

**So, don't be shy! Show or tell what you think would be a great logo and design for our site!**

*I suggest publishing one design by answer so that we, the community, can vote on it. But don't hesitate to create more than one if you feel inspired!*

Comment: Worth noting that the site will not get a design until it *graduates* (see [the current graduation policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites)). It's unlikely the site will get a design until it gets over 10 questions/day, which could take a while, unfortunately (the average beta length varies a lot!). You could write a userscript like [PPCG did](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7897/graduation-design-ideas/7955#7955) though, if you're artistically inclined.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I'm aware of that. :| The idea of launching that subject this early is to let community the time to imagine and create a design they would see on our site. I don't want them to feel in a hurry to propose something. Once graduated, maybe designers would make us a theme quicker if we suggest them some. Also, the user-script is a great idea in the meanwhile. :)